# How to convert ISO Date to DateTime in php?

Tags: php, mongodb, date, laravel, datetime

How to convert the ISO date in mongodb:

```
ISODate("2015-11-20T10:00:09.809Z")
```

to php date ?

Comment: where is your date stored ? In a PHP variable ?

Comment: How are you querying the database. With doctrine? If it is of type MongoDate, try ``$date->toDateTime();``

Comment: In mongodb. I need to output in the form M-d-Y.

Answer (score 3):

You should check [MongoDate](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php):

```
//build a MongoDate object from a string format
$mongoDate = new MongoDate( strtotime("2010-01-15 00:00:00") );
```

Once you have a `MongoDate` object (this is probably your case), you can convert it to a `DateTime` object this way:

```
//get a DateTime object
$phpDate = $mongoDate->toDateTime();
```

And finally convert it to the format you want:

```
$phpDate->format('M-d-Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

$date = '2011-09-02T18:00:00';

$time = strtotime($date);

$fixed = date('l, F jS Y \a\t g:ia', $time);

Answer (score 0):

when you extract ISODate("2015-11-20T10:00:09.809Z") from MongoDB
you will get two different timestamps  for date=>**sec** and time=>**usec**

**Example:**

```
"created_at":{"sec":1592249762,"usec":53000}
```

Then you can add both sec and usec and you will get new timestamp.

```
$newTimeStamp = $created_at->sec+$created_at->usec; 

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newTimeStamp);
```